# Laravel 5.2 Redirect admin page after login as admin

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.2 has been out for some time now. Yes, it has new auth function which is very good. Specially for beginners.
My question, 
How to check if user is admin and then redirect safely to admin/dashboard properly? I know one way is to use admin flag in database but can any of you show some example?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Hei, i did few things but i need someone to show me how to do it after php artisan make:auth command.

Answer (score 9):

go to AuthController.php and add this method

where role is the user role as defined in the database.

```
protected function authenticated($request,$user){
    if($user->role === 'admin'){
        return redirect()->intended('admin'); //redirect to admin panel
    }

    return redirect()->intended('/'); //redirect to standard user homepage
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**As in Laravel 5.3 / 5.4**

Add following line to create_users_table migration.

```
$table->boolean('is_admin');
```

Add following method to LoginController.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( $user->is_admin ) {
        return redirect('/admin/home');
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Additional note don't forget to add the following lines to RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        // the following 3 lines
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin) { 
            return redirect('/admin/home');
        }

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Otherwise if you e.g. type yourdomain/login and your logged in as admin it would be redirected to home instead of admin/home.

Answer (score 1):

AuthController extends the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait, which has a public method named redirectPath. In my case I would extend that method on the AuthController and I'd put my logic there:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user->myMethodToCheckIfUserHasAnAdminRoleLikeAnEmailOrSomethingLikeThat()) {
        redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }

    redirect('home');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in **Auth/LoginController** there is `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`
change **'/home'** to **'/loginin'** for example, and create a new controller and in the controller get the information of the user and check if he is a admin or not and then redirect him to the proper page