# Laravel: How to redirect to page depends on role

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 types of login, Admin and Customer.
if wanted to log into customer dashboard with admin credintals it wonts login and this is what I want, but if I login using customer credintals will redirect me to customer dashboard, but if I wanted to open the admin dashboard in the same time it will redirects me to the Admin dashboard without checking the role id which must be 1 not 2 as in this code:

**Admin: Dashboard\LoginController**

```
public function postLogin(request $request){
    $auth=auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>1]);
    if($auth)
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    return view('Dashboard.login');
}


public function getLogin(){
    if(Auth::guard('web')->check()){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    return view('Dashboard.login');
}
```

**Customer: customer\LoginController**

```
public function postLogin(request $request){
    $auth=auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>2]);
    if($auth)
    {
        return redirect()->route('customer');
    }
    return redirect()->route('/');
}

public function getLogin(){
    if(Auth::guard('web')->check()){
        return redirect()->route('customer');
    }
    return view('index.mainpage.home');
}
```

Comment: @GhadahSalman: Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048732/laravel-5-3-login-redirect-to-different-pages-for-multiple-users)

Comment: You can make use of my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501968/auth-and-user-management-in-laravel-rest-api/46503658#46503658 - only change where you need it

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be handled only after authentication was done and then app decides to redirects the user to correct route according to its role :)

It's only one checking, not per requests checking >> It's middlewares job.

there is a method inside of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait named `authenticated` with this `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` signature that you can override it inside of `LoginController`. You can check user's role and then redirect him to the right place.

As an example:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

We have two scenarios (as far as I found):

**Scenario 1**: User (with any types) login to the site and we want to redirect him to the corresponding panel (for example if he has admin role, so redirect him to admin panel).

**Scenario 2**: If the normal user goes to `/admin` we want to prevent him from access to admin panel and redirect back to home page or faced him with `403 Forbidden` error page.

In the first scenario, you can redirect the user from LoginController by checking its role (I had explained above).

And in the second, you need a middleware for your admin routes group which check user's role and if it's not an admin user so redirect him or abort it.

Comment: didn't understand Im new in laravel :(

Comment: @GhadahSalman Did you found `LoginController` inside of `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`?

Comment: yes and it has only this function:     protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except'->'logout']);
    }
}

Comment: function authenticated has been found in AuthenticatesUsers.php

Comment: function authenticated has been found in AuthenticatesUsers.php

Comment: ok now if I add the content of authenticated function, nothing change, may I have to change something in web.php? the logging working fine if I went to /admin the login modal work fine for only the admin credentials but if I went to the customer dashboard it will open, so do you think redirect will solve this problem? How??

Comment: @GhadahSalman One question, Is that your login page is separated for Normal-Users and Admin-Users?

Comment: If your login page is separated so you only need to use redirect the user to the right place.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048503/laravel-5-2-redirect-admin-page-after-login-as-admin)

Comment: well, I have 3 type of users: Admin, customer, vendor but I want to login as customer and vendor from one popup modal window using menu item sign in, but if want to access the admin dashboard then I have to go to url: /admin

Comment: as I understood according to your comments, you have a modal (login form) that your users can log-in through it and if the user which just logged-in is `admin` type of user so you want to redirect it to `/admin` automatically. Is it right?

Comment: no its not like that, you know its like control panel, so to access you have to put in url /admin but for normal user from website only u just click on sign in and then if your account has the role customer it will redirect to customer dashboard and if vendor then to vendo dashboard,
the problem if I logged using customer information and went to admin dashboard I will access without logging, hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

in AdminController just added

$this->middleware('auth:admin');